# How to work with records using file stream I/O instead of the 'old' I/O

Tags: file, delphi, io, record, delphi-10.1-berlin

Never learnt to work with streams for reading / writing data, instead I'm using the old Pascal way. Now everybody says this is not efficient and I would like to learn the file stream way, but can't really work with the tutorials that are available. I am using Excel to create and manage datasets (big data tables with one or two headers). I save these as *.txt files (tab delimited). These files I read with Delphi to fill my records and arrays, etc. Below a simplified code example of what I am doing now. If it makes sense to replace this by data streams, could somebody give me a code example of how this would work? Thanks - Fred

```
Type
  TMyRecord = record        // in reality my record file is more complex
     ID : integer;
     Tekst  : string;
     R1 : char;
  end;

Procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  MainDir   : string; // local directory of the executable  
  Tfile     : textfile;
  Fname, T  : string;
  N     : integer;
  C     : char;
  MyData    : TMyRecord;
begin
   MainDir := GetCurrentDir;
   Fname := MainDir + '/Data/File1.txt'; // File1.txt = tab delimited text file
   AssignFile(Tfile, Fname);
   N := 0;
   Try
     If FileExists(FName) then begin
       reset(Tfile);
       while not EOF(Tfile) do begin // find number of record lines
         readln(Tfile);
         N := N + 1;    // not used here, but N = total # of records; required to know! 
       end;
       N := N-1; // correct for the header line not used here
       Reset(Tfile);
       Readln(Tfile); // read the header (no record data), skip
       T := '';
       while not EOF(Tfile) do begin
         Read(Tfile, MyData.ID, C); // C = read the tab
         Read(Tfile, C);
         while C <> #9 do begin
           T := T + C;
           Read(Tfile, C);
         end;
         MyData.Tekst := T;
         Read(TFile, MyData.R1);
         Readln(Tfile); // proceed to the next line
       end;
     end;
   Finally
     closefile(Tfile);
```

Comment: This code seems wasteful, reading the file twice. I'd process this using a line reader component, and then parse each line for tabs.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan is right. `T := T + C;` isn't ideal, either.

Comment: Before you go on, you should ask yourself what your goal is. Do you want to do this efficiently, or do you want to use a more modern idiom? Because if it is the former then you can carry on with class Pascal I/O and massively optimise your existing code.

Comment: Users of traditional file io are often encouraged here to use modern Delphi streams instead, and there is a lot to be said for them.  If you prefer to stick with more traditional stuff, you might take a look at Delphi's "file of record" support.

Comment: David, good point! I can do it reading the file only once. But I would like to be using the streams (as was my question). Unless this will not be better than the (improved) classical method. (Note that I don't know the length of the 'MyData,Tekst' string.)       File of method: I know that method, but I will still first need to convert my .txt file into a file of TRecord, won't I?